# Can't upload an image/file from iPhone SE

Tags: ios, iphone, upload, ionic2

I'm developing an app where, at some point, you can upload an image or a file. On Android I use a filechooser plugin that works fine. No problem with that. But, when I tested my app on Apple devices, this is what happened:

iPhone 5s (10.3.3) - OK

iPhone 5c (10.3.2) - OK

iPhone 6s (10.3.2) - OK

iPad (9.3.5) - OK

iPhone SE (10.3.2) - FAIL

As you see, the only device where I couldn't upload anything was the iPhone SE. When you try to upload something, nothing happens. The iOS native filechooser shows up, you select some file or make a photo, press "Ok"... and that's all. `e.target.files` is empty.

I can't understand why the app works on iPad, iPhone 5/6, iOS 9/10 but not on the iPhone SE. What's special about this model? What I missing here?

By the way, I'm using Ionic 2.2.

P.S. Excuse my english.

===

**UPDATED**

```
// HTML
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)" />

// TS
    handleFileSelect(evt) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                // ...
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files); // empty on iPhone SE
        }
```

Comment: How about posting some code then?

Comment: You have a bug on line 47 of your code.

Comment: Code is simple, as I said, I'm using "evt.target.files". Anyway, now you have the code.

Comment: what's your os version ?

Comment: try evt.currentTarget.files?  sorry , i just guess.